# This One Goes With Five

Tags: rebus, language

This one goes with five

What is the following Rebus?

[image: This one goes with five]

Hint

> It's a number

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The picture can be read as:

> German dog, red you, sand

Which can then be parsed as

> "Hund" *(German for 'dog')* + red + thou *(meaning you)* + sand

which gives

> Hundred thousand

As for the title, it's surprisingly literal!

> This one (1) goes with 5 (zeros)  = 100,000

Comment: You figured it out, Great. Also it should explain One with Five clue.

Comment: Ooh, I like that.  How does the clue play in?  "This one goes with five"

Comment: How many zeros@will

Comment: Added an explanation!

Comment: doh!  I should have caught that.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a stretch, but I'm going to go with:

> 5,000

Reasoning

> The "U" and the "Sand" put me on the track of "thousand". I couldn't come up with many other words ending in "usand", but the dog threw me. How is "tho" a dog? However, now that you've hinted that it is in fact a number...

> Dog = Fido, which sounds an awful lot like "Fitho" or "Five tho".

> Fidousand = Five Thousand

Comment: Part of the answer is correct. Look at the tags